# Record not saved on Heroku, but is on Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I have funciton that creates a new Contract object and saves it when a subscription request is approved. It's called in the Subscription update action and is extracted into it's own class rather than sitting on a the Model or in the Controller.

On Heroku it shows a 500 in the log, but provides no message on the issue. The other lines of code continue to run.

Full block of code:

```
#Check to see the status of the subscription and that all of the checks have been completed
        if @subscription.Approved == "In Review" or @subscription.Approved == "Pending" && @subscription.CompanyNameCheck == "Approved" &&  @subscription.CompanyAddressCheck == "Approved" &&  @subscription.CompanyVATCheck == "Approved" && @subscription.CompanyKVKNumberCheck == "Approved" && @subscription.KVKCheck == "Approved" && @subscription.IDCheck == "Approved"
          #If everything is approved, then set the Subscription to approved and set the date
           @subscription.Approved = "Approved"
           @subscription.AcceptDate = Date.current
           @subscription.save!
           # Create a contract for the subscription
           @company = Company.find(@subscription.company_id)
           @contract = Contract.new(:company_id => @company.id, :subscription_type => @subscription.product.name, :company_type => @company.legal_entity, :subscription_id => @subscription.id, :CompanyName => @company.name) 
           @contract.save! 
           EventMailer.subscription_contract(@subscription, @contract).deliver
        end
```

Lines not executed:

```
       @company = Company.find(@subscription.company_id)
       @contract = Contract.new(:company_id => @company.id, :subscription_type =>      @subscription.product.name, :company_type => @company.legal_entity, :subscription_id => @subscription.id, :CompanyName => @company.name) 
       @contract.save! 
       EventMailer.subscription_contract(@subscription, @contract).deliver
```

Heroku Logs:

```
    2014-10-27T08:31:27.296463+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/subscriptions/8/edit" host=tso.herokuapp.com request_id=a7ba490f-31fd-49ef-b282-3d65e978cab6 fwd="213.127.222.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=530ms status=200 bytes=10399
    2014-10-27T08:31:38.053338+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/subscriptions/8" host=tso.herokuapp.com request_id=2f51d682-8d10-4709-9390-b1eb6d724144 fwd="213.127.222.82" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=233ms status=500 bytes=1543
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add **gem 'rails_12factor'** to your Gemfile.Use this link [heroku setup](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-rails4)

Comment: I've added the rails_12factor gem and have seen that the issue seems to be when the contract is created  `2014-10-27T10:31:54.618554+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.4ms)  BEGIN
2014-10-27T10:31:54.623263+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.0ms)  SELECT MAX("contracts"."id") AS max_id FROM "contracts"
2014-10-27T10:31:54.623268+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.0ms)  SELECT MAX("contracts"."id") AS max_id FROM "contracts"
2014-10-27T10:31:54.625577+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
2014-10-27T10:31:54.625583+00:00 app[web.1]:    (2.1ms)  ROLLBACK
` What's not clear is why the SELECT MAX fails

Comment: Please paste your code for model and controller so that can rectify the problem

Comment: Found the solution - it was an issue in the Model that set the ID value for the Contract. Your request for the model gave me the clue to look at the model in more detail and the only code that it could have been was the before_create callback that set the id to start from 1000 rather than 1. `self.id = [1000, self.class.maximum(:id)+1].max if self.id.nil?` removing that code fixed the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Logentries](https://addons.heroku.com/logentries) to try expand error message or try add [rails_12factor](https://github.com/heroku/rails_12factor) gem

Comment: Ok. Let we try create `@contract` object in heroku Rails console. Post here a system answer, please.